# Как сделать из обьекта массив всех комбинаций?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

У меня есть обьект к примеру

```
let a = {
    "color": "blue,white, black",
    "size": "M,L",
    "length": "23,44"
}
```

Мне нужен массив со всеми комбинациями:

```
[
    {"color": "blue", "size": "M", "length": "23"},
    {"color": "blue", "size": "M", "length": "44"}, 
    {"color": "blue", "size": "L", "length": "23"},
    {"color": "blue", "size": "L", "length": "44"},
    {"color": "white", "size": "M", "length": "23"},
]
```

Я пробую сделать это через цикл:

```
let arr = [];
for (const obj in a) {
    const key = obj;
    const aRR = a[key].split(',')
    const object = {};
    for (const item of aRR) {
      object[key] = item;
      arr.push({[obj]: item})
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите какие-то попытки решить проблему

Comment: Проблема в том, что обьект будет иметь разное количество свойств, и разную длину массива, который происходит из .split(",")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант - можно рекурсивно пройтись по ключам объекта, итерируя его значения

```js
const A = {
  color: "blue,white,black",
  size: "M,L",
  length: "23,44"
};

function getVariants(from) {
  const result = [];
  const buffer = {};
  const keys = Object.keys(from);
  const next = (index = 0) => {
    const current = keys[index];
    for (const item of from[current].split(",")) {
      buffer[current] = item;
      if (index + 1 === keys.length) {
        result.push({ ...buffer });
      } else {
        next(index + 1);
      }
    }
  };
  next();
  return result;
}

const variants = getVariants(A);
console.log(variants);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! Это работает